# ClickHouse How to change queue_max_wait_ms value in system.settings table

Tags: clickhouse, tabix

My ClickHouse queries are failing because of exceeding max waiting time with the error:

```sh
Code: 159, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Timeout exceeded: elapsed 5.380073004 seconds, maximum: 5
```

The timeout is specified in *system.settings* table but I can not find a way to change it.

It doesn't exist in */etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml* and */etc/clickhouse-server/user.xml* files.

Could someone please advice me how to change the value?

Comment: You need to tune receive_timeout at a client side.
Depends on error message and client library / API

Comment: Denis, thank you for your feedback I'm getting the following error message:Code: 159, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Timeout exceeded: elapsed 5.380073004 seconds, maximum: 5: and Using Tabix web based console as a client. I'm not quite sure how to change wait timeout as there is no corresponded parameter.

Comment: It looks like your execution time is restricted by user profile - see [max_execution_time](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/query_complexity/#max-execution-time) in */user.d/user.xml*. 
If it is correct you need to use another account to execute a query that has a more suitable configuration or increase the limit for this user.

Comment: To check the current value of [max_execution_time](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/operations/settings/query_complexity/#max-execution-time) execute query "select * from system.settings where name = 'max_execution_time'".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@antonk it's a tabix default setting. Under settings on the right / max execution time 5 seconds

Comment: Denis, thanks a lot. I've found it in tabix settings. Thanks you for your support